# Metrics sum of label in rate or irate

Tags: prometheus

I'm calculate CPU usage of process by process-exporter, but it have two different label in one metric for example:

```
namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname="(sd-pam)",instance="localhost:9256",job="process_exporter",mode="system"}
```

```
namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname="(sd-pam)",instance="localhost:9256",job="process_exporter",mode="user"}
```

i need sum two of it to have % cpu usage of process.

i have tried with this, but the code won't show anything

```
topk(5,
rate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname=~"$processes",instance="$host",mode="user"}[20s]) + 
rate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname=~"$processes",instance="$host",mode="system"}[20s])
or 
(
irate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname=~"$processes",instance="$host",mode="user"}[5m]) +
irate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname=~"$processes",instance="$host",mode="system"}[5m])))
```

but it work with this (when i change all to user or system)

```
topk(5,
rate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname=~"$processes",instance="$host",mode="system"}[20s]) + 
rate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname=~"$processes",instance="$host",mode="system"}[20s])
or 
(
irate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname=~"$processes",instance="$host",mode="system"}[5m]) +
irate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname=~"$processes",instance="$host",mode="system"}[5m])))
```

What should i do to have sum two of this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions when label matching to aggregate the two time series. It would look something like this:

> sum(rate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname=~"$processes",instance="$host", mode=~"system|user"}[1m])) by (groupname, instance)

The above gives you the total CPU used by `system` and `user`, aggregated by groupname and instance.